# How can I open TomTom navigation app from my phonegap app?

Tags: android, cordova, tomtom

I recently deployed my phonegap app on TomTom device running android V4.3

Now I want to open the navigation app from my phonegap app and pass coordinates to show locations on the Map. I can't find a way to accomplish this

Comment: probably with an intent like here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2662531/launching-google-maps-directions-via-an-intent-on-android ?

Comment: I added this phonegap plugin https://github.com/Initsogar/cordova-webintent, but I don't know the Intent trigger for eg: "geo://" for TomTom navigation app

Comment: may be by writing your own plugin class like : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14321376/open-an-activity-from-a-cordovaplugin

Answer (score 1):

You can use this plugin, it'll do what you want to accomplish: https://github.com/metaware/tomtomplugin