# Can't start an activity from a cordova plugin using .aar files

Tags: android-activity, cordova-plugins

I am trying to write a simple cordova-plugin for android, but I am stuck into a crash that I don't know how to resolve.

I basically followed these steps to create simple plugin and it worked fine.

http://www.mat-d.com/site/tutorial-creating-a-cordova-phonegap-plugin-for-android-app/

Yet, my plugin must call an activity that is packaged as an .aar file. Basically I have a full blown application with java/layouts that needs to be triggered by the plugin.

I followed these steps to add my .aar file to the android build of cordova.

[Cordova plugin development - adding aar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30757208/cordova-plugin-development-adding-aar)

It also worked. Now, I have so far in my plugin structure these files (admittedly is pretty hacked right now since I kept most of original names):

[image]

in my yourFile.gradle I have this:

```
repositories{    
  jcenter()
  flatDir{
      dirs 'libs'
   }
}

dependencies {
   compile(name:'mylittlelibrary-release', ext:'aar')
   compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'
}

android {
  packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
  }
}
```

and the main part of my "CoolPlugin.java" looks like this:

```
public class CoolPlugin extends CordovaPlugin {
    public CoolPlugin() {}
    public void initialize(CordovaInterface cordova, CordovaWebView webView) {
        super.initialize(cordova, webView);
    }
    public boolean execute(final String action, JSONArray args, CallbackContext callbackContext) throws JSONException {
        cordova.getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                final Context context = cordova.getActivity().getApplicationContext();
                try {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(context, testv.com.mylittlelibrary.MainActivity.class);
                    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                    cordova.getActivity().startActivity(intent);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    String errorText = e.toString();
                    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, errorText, duration);
                    toast.show();
                }
```

My "mylittlelibrary-release.aar" has its main activity under the namespace "testv.com.mylittlelibrary" so the MainActivity.java looks like this:

```
package testv.com.mylittlelibrary;

import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;

import com.android.volley.*;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.*;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        etc...
```

I was reading the thread below, and looks like I need in somehow register the main activity of my aar file.

[open an activity from a CordovaPlugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14321376/open-an-activity-from-a-cordovaplugin)

I am not totally sure how to do this, so I went inside the auto-generated AndroidManifest.xml under

C:\cordova\hello\platforms\android\AndroidManifest.xml

and hacked the activity with the namespace inside as such:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<manifest android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="0.0.1" package="com.example.hello" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <supports-screens android:anyDensity="true" android:largeScreens="true" android:normalScreens="true" android:resizeable="true" android:smallScreens="true" android:xlargeScreens="true" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <application android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name" android:supportsRtl="true">
        <activity android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale" android:label="@string/activity_name" android:launchMode="singleTop" android:name="MainActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault.NoActionBar" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <intent-filter android:label="@string/launcher_name">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:label="@string/activity_name"
        android:launchMode="singleTop"
        android:name="testv.com.mylittlelibrary.MainActivity">
        </activity>
    </application>
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="17" android:targetSdkVersion="23" />
</manifest>
```

I installed the plugin and ran the app using:

```
cordova plugin add c:/CoolPlugin/
cordova build android
cordova run android
```

there is button in the html file that triggers the plugin, which then triggers my activity as you see on the "MainActivity" of the "mylittlelibrary-release.aar" file.

Yet, I keep getting this crash. I believe the android plugin cannot resolve the namespace properly and throws this exception.

```
com.example.hello E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.hello, PID: 13119
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Ltestv/com/mylittlelibrary/MainActivity;
    at CoolPlugin$1.run(CoolPlugin.java:59)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5835)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
```

I also believe is has something to do with the proper registering the MainActivity under the testv.com.mylittlelibrary. But I can't figure out how to do in in cordova. I need to resolve this, so I am glad to give you points of my reputation for a solid answer that unblocks me.

thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

nevermind, it was simple mistake. The library missed some imports and a theme. This fixed the issue.

Manifest:

```
android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light"
```

Gradle:

```
dependencies {
   compile(name:'mylittlelibrary-release', ext:'aar')
   compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:23.1.0'
   compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.0'
   compile 'com.android.support:gridlayout-v7:23.1.1'
   compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.0'
   compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.0'
```

Comment: Hi , Glad that you worked out a resolution. I need your suggestion for the below one. I have an aar file which is included similar way which has classes and methods to be referred in Activity. But I need to create an Activity which will reside outside of aar file and inside my Cordova Plugin. How can this be achieved? Any suggestion?

Comment: I tried your way as well. Creating a Library. Tested the library with Native android application and works well. But when included in hybrid application as an pluginname.aar file with modifications including manifest in hello\platforms\android\AndroidManifest.xml , I am getting error . Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "nativeplugin.cclib.MainActivity" on path: DexPathList. Any idea why its not able to refer?

Comment: Can you look into http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41245394/start-activity-inside-cordova-plugins-aars-file-in-ionic2  link which has similar issue ?

Comment: @Stallion the .aar file can contain as many activities and you want and you can fire any of them at any time. I believe you may have issues on your gradle files. This is when I had path problems with the cordova plugin. I posted a snipped of the code I use that work for me. Hope it helps.

Comment: thanks for your support .. the flow is working successfully now