# How to pass non-primitive Object from Java to JS by Android addJavascriptInterface?

Tags: java, android

I've had a trouble on this topic (for days).

For instance, basically, I want to pass a Java WebSocketClient object to Android Webview JS **on demand**, so wrote a code referring to:

- http://foretribe.blogspot.com.au/2013/08/how-to-make-android-webview-support.html
- https://github.com/thinksource/vw_websocket/blob/master/src/com/strumsoft/websocket/phonegap/WebSocketFactory.java

**JAVA**

```
    wv.addJavascriptInterface(new WebSocketFactory(), "factoryJ");

    public class WebSocketFactory {
            //.............
            public WebSocket getInstance(String url) { 
               socket = new WebSocket(new URI(url)); 
               return socket; 
            }   
    }
```

**JS**

```
 var url = "ws:someaddress";
 var ws = factoryJ.getInstance(url);  
 console.log(ws.toString())  // object pointer displayed
 console.log(ws.getReadyState()); //Uncaught Error: Error calling method on NPObject!
```

`Uncaught Error: Error calling method on NPObject!`

This concept does not work at least for me avove Android4.2+.,
because `addJavascriptInterface()` only works with Java primitive types and Strings.

cf)

- [Passing a JavaScript object using addJavascriptInterface() on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2250917/passing-a-javascript-object-using-addjavascriptinterface-on-android)
- [Error calling method on NPObject! in Android 2.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3344256/error-calling-method-on-npobject-in-android-2-2)

**As far as I know, the only way to pass JAVA object to JS is :**

```
wv.addJavascriptInterface(JavaObject, "JsObject");
```

Sure, this should work fine as long as a passing `JavaObject` is pre-determined, but since WebSocket Object(s) is on-demand, I need to hack somehow for this.

So, I prepare `JavaObject` as some Array of WebSocket .

```
   WebSocketNew[] ws = new WebSocketNew[99999];
   wv.addJavascriptInterface(ws, "wsJ");
```

Unfortunately, the JS treats `wsJ[n]` as `undefined` ; appears it's also not allowed to pass ArrayObject.

I've read `JSON` or `JSON array` of Java can be passed, but it's `string` after all and cannot be this solution, am I correct?

Probably, back in old days, Android Java-JS interaction is implemented more freely, but under security issues, they restrict more (the annotation `@JavascriptInterface` is the one, and not only this but also other factors ) [Android 4.2.1, WebView and javascript interface breaks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14031635/android-4-2-1-webview-and-javascript-interface-breaks)

How to pass non-primitive Object from Java to JS by Android addJavascriptInterface?

Any thought?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been one of the most hectic hack for me.

The major problem occurs from Android `UI-thread` and `non-UI-thread` bind with `addJavascriptInterface`

Firstly, **my mention: 
*As far as I know, the only way to pass JAVA object to JS is :
wv.addJavascriptInterface(JavaObject, "JsObject");*
is wrong.**

In fact, I could pass `WebSocketNew`= my custom Java object properly to JS as return value of `getInstance`.

**However**, the object intended to pass/return to JS must be in scope of Android `UI-thread`.

If we just do `return new WebSocketNew(new URI(url)))`, it's not found by JS, probably because JS runs in UI-thread, and the origin runs on `non-UI-thread` of `addJavascriptInterface`.

As I mentioned earlier, since WebScoket instance is on-demand, so I decided to create Object pool in `UI-thread` first.
This can be done with HashMap with the requested url String.

Java

```
    final HashMap<String, WebSocketNew> ws = new HashMap<>();
    //runs on non-UI-thread
    class WebSocketFactory
    {
        public WebSocketFactory()
        {
        }

        @JavascriptInterface
        public WebSocketNew getInstance(String url)
        {
            System.out.println("============WebSocketFactory============getInstance  " + url);

            try
            {
                ws.put(url, new WebSocketNew(new URI(url)));
                ws.get(url).connect();

                System.out.println("=====WebSocketNew=====" + url + "  " + ws.get(url).getReadyState());

                return ws.get(url);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                System.out.println("==========ERROR");
                return null;
            }
        }
    }

    wv.addJavascriptInterface(new WebSocketFactory(), "factoryJ");

    wv.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/Content/app.html");
```

JS

```
         window.WebSocket = function(url)
         {
               console.log('####################creating new WebScoketInstance JS ' + url);

               var p = {
                     url: null
               };
               p.url = url;

               var ws = factoryJ.getInstance(p.url);

               var obj = {
                     send: function(data)
                     {
                           console.log('---  send: function(data)-----  ws.send1(data);------');
                           ws.send1(data);
                     },
              //.......
              //.......

               }
               return obj;


         };
```

The JS code is related to topic : [JavaScript Event implementation to Closure based Object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21108540/javascript-event-implementation-to-closure-based-object)

Comment: It is interesting how did you manage to get WebSocket object from Java into Javascript code. I have tried the same for the other custom objects, but it in javascript code I can see only empty object.

Comment: Can you add the code related to WebSocketNew? is it just the object that i want to send to JS? Can you elaborate/share the code related to WebSocketNew?

Answer (score 3):

You are correct that Javascript Interface methods can only return strings and primitive types. If you need to return a more complex object, you can try serializing the object to JSON. But, that only works for model-level objects. If you need to return a class which contains functionality, the only way I know of to do this is to wrap the class, and expose each of its methods as a @JavascriptInterface. For instance:

```
class Foo {
    private WrappedClass myWrappedClass;

    public Foo(WrappedClass classToWrap) {
        myWrappedClass = classToWrap;
    }

    @JavascriptInterface
    public String doSomething1() {
        return myWrappedClass.doSomething1();
    }

    @JavascriptInterface
    public int doSomething2() {
        return myWrappedClass.doSomething2();
    }

    // Etc.
}
```

This is pretty tedious.

But, it looks like you're trying to use websockets. Have you considered Socket.io? It would allow you to use web sockets in Javascript, rather than relying on a JavascriptInterface.

http://socket.io

Comment: Thanks for your advise. In fact, surely I considered to use socket.io or others, but I try to implement my ownlight-weight RPC with raw websocket. I will examine your solution and get back soon.

Comment: I solved, and posted my answer. I found the point you mention is covered in my code already. The problem has been due to another aspect. Thanks again. @Jeffrey Portouw